# cover bigger number, with selection of given smaller numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers

I have an array of numbers (e.g. [2, 4, 5, 7]) and have to find the best possible combination to "cover" a bigger number, "cover" meaning here that the sum of the selected numbers should be at least equal to the bigger number. The sum of the selection should be as close as possible to the bigger number and in case of 2+ possible optimal selections, the one which uses fewer numbers in its sum should be chosen, in case there are still 2+ possible options, the one whose chosen numbers come further in front of the array should be returned. A number cant be used twice, unless it appears twice in the given array.
example:

```
[2, 4, 5, 7], to cover 10 => [4,7] since 11 is the closest to 10 (and at least 10) possible

[5, 6, 3, 6, 20], to cover 18 => [20], since 20 is the closest to 18 (and at least 18) possible and [20] uses fewer numbers than [5, 6, 3, 6]
```

My problem is that I have a tree like data structure and want to collapse as few elements as possible, while allowing the user the see as much as possible without scrolling. You dont have to code anything just an Idea for an algorithm would be enough (my implementation would be in js though).

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: 5+6+6 is closer to 18 than 20 is? If you want to weigh the count of chosen number against the closeness, you must tell us how exactly you want to weigh it.

Comment: closest bigger sum*, will edit it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: when your input is [2, 4, 5, 7] shouldn't the answer be [4, 7] as it uses only two elements in the array than three of [2, 4, 5] and result of both is 11?

Comment: @Breakpoint yes it should be - as you can see not an easy problem xD

Comment: Do you want the numbers in same relative order or are they allowed to be sorted?

Comment: Please let me know the length limit of array.

Comment: Too computationally expensive.

Comment: @Breakpoint order doesnt matter

Comment: @TopDeveloper the length is based on user input i would guess on average 5, at most 50 - so 100 should be save - edit: I could also inplement it in a way, that if a node has more than 5 children (5+ elements in the array), I would only show the first 5 elements, creating a maximum length of 5

Comment: An Array of `10` gives you `Math.pow(10, 10)`, just to cover the combinations.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
const arr_origin = [2,4,5,7,2,4,5,20];
const arr_unique = [...new Set(arr_origin)];
const cover_num = 10;

var closest_sum = arr_origin.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0);
var arr_optimal = arr_unique;

find([], 0);

function find(arr_now, idx) {
    const sum = arr_now.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0);

    if ( (cover_num <= sum && sum < closest_sum) || 
         (cover_num <= sum && sum == closest_sum && arr_now.length < arr_optimal.length) )
    {
        closest_sum = sum;
        arr_optimal = arr_now;
    }

    if (idx < arr_unique.length) {
        // skip this element
        find(arr_now, idx+1);

        // add this element into array
        var arr_new = arr_now.slice(0);
        arr_new.push(arr_unique[idx]);
        find(arr_new, idx+1);
    }
}
```

This will gives:

```
// [2, 4, 5, 7], to cover 10 => [4,7], 11
// [5, 6, 3, 6, 20], to cover 18 => [20], 20
// [2,4,5,7,2,4,5,20], to cover 10 => [4,7], 11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With a few initial tests, this solution appears to work:

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/LightpinkExpensiveMethods)

```
const maxValue = (array, targetValue) => {
  array.sort((a, b) => (a < b) ? -1 : 1)
  let sums = []
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    let addends = []
    let addendX = array[i]
    let currentSum = addendX
    let closest = (currentSum >= targetValue)
      ? true
      : false
    addends.push(addendX)
    for(let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if(closest) break
      let addendY = array[j]
      if(
        !closest &&
        currentSum + addendY >= targetValue
      ) {
        currentSum += addendY
        closest = true
      } else {
        currentSum += addendY
      }
      addends.push(addendY)
    }
    sums.push({
      sum: currentSum,
      addends: addends,
    })
  }
  return sums.sort((a, b) => (a.sum < b.sum) ? -1 : 1)[0]
}
console.log(maxValue([2, 4, 5, 7], 11))
/*
{ sum: 11, addends: [ 2, 4, 5 ] }
*/
console.log(maxValue([5, 6, 3, 6, 20], 18))
/*
{ sum: 20, addends: [ 3, 5, 6, 6 ] }
*/
```

It could probably use some optimization or may produce inaccurate results, but you would have to provide more test cases for me to work through those issues.

Comment: your function seems to return a number, not an array - it should return the individual parts, which together add up to the number your function returns - also calling `maxValue([5, 6, 3, 6, 20], 18)` returns 23, which should be 20 i believe

Comment: @Teiem I refactored the solution and return the sum with the addends. 

If you have more test cases I would want to test more, but I think it is working.

Comment: it is returning results, but not optimal ones (e.g. `{11, [4, 9]}` and `{20, [20]}`) an other case `maxValue([567,123,2,1233,6,5,4,9], 18)` returns `{20, [5, 6, 9]}`, though `{18, [5, 4, 9]}` would be better - still thank you :)